# Sirikit extension with coredata

Tags: core-data, ios-app-extension

So basically I am trying to access persistent container using app groups. This is the code I used to configure core data in AppDelegate:

```
let storeDirectory = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.xxx.xxx.xxx")!
let url = storeDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SirikitWIthCoreDataDemo.momd")
print(url)
let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url)
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "SirikitWIthCoreDataDemo")
container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
```

Now when I check the path, the .momd file is created on the shared container path. So far so good. But now I am trying to access this persistent container to get the context with this code:

```
let storeDirectory = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.xxx.xxx.xxx")!
let url = storeDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SirikitWIthCoreDataDemo.momd")
let managedObjectModelPath = url
let model = NSManagedObjectModel.init(contentsOf: managedObjectModelPath)
let container = NSPersistentContainer.init(name: "SiriKitWIthCoreDataDemo.momd", managedObjectModel: model!)
let ctx = container.viewContext
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Story", in: ctx)
```

But it returns a nil ManagedObjectModel. I can't understand the reason for this. Everything is setup correctly and the path is the same as well. Still it returns nil. Please help me with this. I have been trying to figure this out since yesterday.